# What is the suitable IDE

Tags: ide

I just wanna to know what is the good IDE to start coding with all of the languages mentioned here such as: Java, JavaScript, HTML, CSS, PHP, Android, C#, and SQL.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: That's a very broad mix, and no single IDE will be good for all of that. Try to narrow down your requirements and it should be easier to choose. Start about thinking about *what* you want to do first, then research and select a language based on that, and a suitable IDE should be easy to find.

Comment: NetBeans can do that, except for C#

Comment: Thank you both about clarifying that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans is a good choice. You can code in the following languages with it:

1. Java(for mobile, desktop and Web)
2. C/C++
3. PHP
4. HTML5
5. JavaScript
6. CSS

You can download NetBeans [here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)

Comment: Thank you my friend